# Эффект как у LIDAR в Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытаюсь придумать, как можно реализовать идею с LIDAR в Unity. Я хотел что бы игрок при нажатии на кнопку запускал сканер, который будто светом проходится по окружению, и оставляет там точки. Такое уже есть в одном из режимов Garry's mod, он так же называется LIDAR:

https://youtu.be/C_bGNtgUV-M

Но я не могу никак понять как это можно сделать. Если использовать Raycast, тогда лучей будет слишком много, и это плохо будет для производительности. А в интернете ничего об этом нету. Можете подсказать как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html